# Post rank by views

Tags: views

I want show: Post id 5 has 100 views and rank is 2nd, post id 6 has 90 views and rank is 4th, post id 7 has 1100 views and rank is 1st

I try:

```
$query="SELECT u.*,um.post_id, FIND_IN_SET(
                      um.post_id,(SELECT GROUP_CONCAT( um.post_id ORDER BY um.meta_value * 1 DESC)
                              FROM $wpdb->postmeta
                              WHERE um.meta_key ='views')
                           ) AS rank
        FROM $wpdb->postmeta um
        JOIN $wpdb->posts u ON(u.ID = um.post_id)
        WHERE u.post_type = 'post' AND u.post_status = 'publish' AND u.ID = '".$post_id."'
        ";
```

but not working (return false), please help me.

Comment: So, basically, you need posts sorted by I'd, and not by post views

Comment: @goose Where's the views data coming from? What is generating/tracking the number of views per post?

Comment: @BradDalton seems it is come from a custom field from what I can see from the OP

Answer (score 1):

Is there any specific reason you are using $wpdb? You can do the same with `WP_Query` which is always recommended.

So if your meta key for counting post views is `views` then you can run this `WP_Query` to return top viewed posts. You can also limit results by `posts_per_page`.

```
<?php

    $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'meta_key' => 'views',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
        'posts_per_page' => '30',
    );

    $my_query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if ( $my_query->have_posts() ) :

        $postnum = 1;

        while ( $my_query->have_posts() ) : $my_query->the_post();

            echo "Post id " . $post->ID . " has " . get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'views', true ) . " views and rank is " . $postnum . ".<br />";
            $postnum++;

        endwhile;

    endif;

    wp_reset_postdata();

?>
```

**EDIT 1**

Okey, now I understood what are you asking.
You want to obtain rank of each posts and show it in post list.
To do that first we will need to get all posts sorted by views and store those in an array. After that in each post we will need to find out where each post is located in rank array.

So first we will define global variable in `functions.php` file.

```
$rank_array = array();
```

Now in your template we will run a custom WP_Query to get rank array. Add this somewhere. Must be outside the loop and must be on the theme php file that shows these posts.

```
global $rank_array;

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'meta_key' => 'views',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'fields' => 'ids',
);

$rank_query = new WP_Query( $args );
$rank_array = $rank_query->posts;
```

Now we have all the ranked post IDs in our `$rank_array` array.

Now in your loop where you are outputing your posts list. You will need to find each posts rank with it's ID. This must be used inside the loop.

```
global $rank_array;
$item_rank = array_search( $post->ID, $rank_array ) + 1;
echo "Rank: " . $item_rank . " with " . get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'views', true ) . " views";
```

Comment: No bro, I want to show:
id | post_title | views | rank

Comment: In that case this code will work. Instead of `get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );` in above code you can use your code of what you want to output.

Comment: No. I want show: Post id 5 has 100 views and rank is 1st, post id 6 has 90 views and rank is 2nd,

Comment: Okay I updated the code. Now it will output as you require.

Comment: No bro. I want: Post id 5 has 100 views and rank is 2nd, post id 6 has 90 views and rank is 4, post id 7 has 1100 views and rank is 1st

Comment: Okay, please explain what exactly is the difference? Because I am not able to understand.

Comment: You can see: http://www.animeram.eu/anime-list/search/
Hope you understand me (sory my bad EL)

Comment: Okay I understand now. Please check `Edit 1`.

Comment: @kytdesigner Please always edit your question with new or additional information. Try to avoid excessive discussion in comments as there is [chat] if that is really, really needed. And please, please, please stay away from slang language like "bro". No one is a "bro" of someone in here and non-native speakers might not understand what you mean by saying that. Thank you.

Comment: Thank so much, i try and it work and show rank 1,2,3 because order by views, but i dont want order by views. Please re-open link http://animeram.eu/anime-list/search  to understand me. Again, thank so much bro!

Comment: What? No, it's not showing posts ordered by post views. Posts will be listed as you were doing earlier. The custom query in `EDIT 1` is to know the rank of the post. It does not do anything else because it's outputting only IDs and we have not added any loop with this particular query.

Comment: @kytdesigner Please reread kaiser comment above^^

Comment: @Roberthue: I wrap your code in function get_rank_by_views($post_id) and use it in other loop and seem it'working. If i see a bug i will tell you. Thank so much!

Comment: @Kaiser: Ok. Sorry my bad English because i dont know slang language. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use SQL queries if the job can be done with by the main query, `pre_get_posts` or a custom query, so I'm going to work with a solution that does not involve SQL. I think the answer from @Roberthue was almost there, so I'm just going to extend on that and should be treated as such.

I think the best approach here is to get all posts ordered by views first using the [`meta_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Custom_Field_Parameters) in `WP_Query`. From there, you can use [`uasort`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to sort the posts according to post ID's. The reason for `uasort` is to keep the array keys as the array keys will be used as the ranking parameter for the posts. One thing to remember here is that the array keys starts at `0`, so you will need to add `1` to every key.

Here is the code:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'meta_key' => 'views',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'nopaging' => true,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'fields' => 'ids',
);
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
$post_ranks = $query->posts;

uasort( $post_ranks, function( $a, $b ){
    if ($a == $b) {
        return 0;
    }
        return ($a < $b) ? -1 : 1;  
    } 
);

foreach ($post_ranks as $key=>$post ) {
    $rank = $key + 1;
    $views = get_post_meta( $post, 'views', true );

    echo "Post ID " . $post . " has " . $views . " views and is ranked #" . $rank  . ".<br />";
}
```

This is the expected output

[image]

Comment: Cool! i will try it

Comment: Remember to leave feedback, and also remember to mark the most appropriate answer as correct when done. :-)